# How to sum using YII2 relation hasMany?

Tags: mysql, yii2

I'm using Yii2 and I have two tables:

```
user (id)
answer_points (id, user_id, value)
```

How can I sum all the points of each user in a gridview with filtering, sorting by sum DESC and relation?

```
return $this->hasMany(\frontend\models\Points::className(), 
       ['user_id' => 'id'])->sum('value');
```

Comment: Don't do that, better add a point [counter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#updateCounters%28%29-detail) column to your user.

Answer (score 2):

In your `User` model, you should have this getter

```
public function getPoints()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\frontend\models\Points::className(), ['user_id' => 'id'])->sum('value');
}
```

In your `UserSearch` model, you can do

```
public function search(...) {
    $query = User::find()->joinWith('points'); //<--- alias to the getter defined above
    ...
}
```

Now you should be able to add that column to use that column in your sorts and filters.

Comment: @user5431131 did this answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom dataProvider and use in GridView
And Custom SearchModel.

Comment: This answer should have been a comment.